# Constructor on type 'System.String[]' not found

Tags: tfs, arguments, build-automation, tfsbuild

I defined in my BuildTemplate.xaml a new Argument with Type of String[][]. [image: new Argument in my BuildTemplate]

Now when I open the build template and try to fill the argument I got the error:

> Constructor on type 'System.String[]' not found.

[image: Constructor on type not found]

What's the problem?

Comment: `String[]` does not have default constructor, hence it will not work with a collection editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

Comment: I tried this on a List<string>, which should be an IEnumerable<string>.  I got the same error.